# error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::string []' to 'std::string []'

Tags: c++

now what is wrong with this code!

Header:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Menu
{
public:
    Menu(string []);
    ~Menu(void);

};
```

Implementation:

```
#include "Menu.h"

string _choices[];

Menu::Menu(string items[])
{
    _choices = items;
}

Menu::~Menu(void)
{
}
```

compiler is complaining:

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::string []' to 'std::string []'
There are no conversions to array types, although there are conversions to references or pointers to arrays
```

there is no conversion! so what is it on about?

please help, just need to pass a bloody array of strings and set it to Menu class _choices[] attribute.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Array's cannot be assigned, and your arrays have no sizes anyway. You probably just want a `std::vector`: `std::vector<std::string>`. This is a dynamic array of strings, and can be assigned just fine.

```
// Menu.h
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// **Never** use `using namespace` in a header,
// and rarely in a source file.

class Menu
{
public:
    Menu(const std::vector<std::string>& items); // pass by const-reference

    // do not define and implement an empty
    // destructor, let the compiler do it
};

// Menu.cpp
#include "Menu.h"

// what's with the global? should this be a member?
std::vector<std::string> _choices;

Menu::Menu(const std::vector<std::string>& items)
{
    _choices = items; // copies each element
}
```

Comment: Thanks GMan that was really informative and worked of course.
I've also moved _choices to be a member. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can't define the array as `string _choices[]`, that defines an array with unknown size, which is illegal.

If you change it to `string * _choices` it will work just fine (though be aware it will only copy a pointer to the array, and not clone it all).

Also, don't you want `_choices` to be a field of the class, instead of a global?

Comment: namespace-scope arrays aren't allocated on the stack.